# Receiving 500 internal server error while generating metadata

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, client-object-model, metadata

Receiving 500 internal server error while generating metadata for custom lists.

When trying to access the service an internal server error is received.

I have attached the screenshot of an error.

[image]

Comment: Please add a clear screenshot instead of the uploaded! and add more details about the issue itself, your question is unclear

Comment: I'm trying to access the webservice. It works fine for list like task and other system list. But I receive 500 internal server error while trying for custom list. For an example Companies is a custom list we created but when I try to access it, I receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working with calculated column which includes HTML or JS code. If you have calculated column like this, can you remove the column and try again?

Also, just maybe, it can be case sensitive. Such as /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/test and /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TEST are different. Type your list name exactly what it is.